# Could bitcoins destroy a government

Tags: taxes, government

In theory if bitcoins were to be used by the majority of a population then could the issue arise of a drop in government funds as bitcoins are technically tax free as they is no way of tracking were the transaction is from or who its by.so my question is it possible to destroy a country's government via a large increase in bit coin usages assuming all businesses would be willing to pay employees and sell products via bitcoins?